# How to find the filesize of a flash which is not exactly stored in the temp but redirected by a fd

Tags: linux, flash

flash31 -> /tmp/FlashXXvsg1uY (deleted) directory is /proc/processid

Chrome is downloading a flash and I can see in the proc direcotry the flash file ,

how can I see the current file size of such a file ?

Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stat()` function should work.

In shell, run:

```
stat -L /proc/$PID/fd/$FD
```

or

```
stat -Lc '%s' /proc/$PID/fd/$FD
```